# handle multi request from multi user

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I make a telegram bot with php
I have a group that use bot.
my problem is when several people click on one inline keyboard button I want the button to work for the first user that clicked and for the rest who clicked at the same time does not work.
how can I handle such request that must execute one time ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't know PHP, so my examples are in Python. First, add the inline button press handler. e.g.

```
# when initialising the bot
dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(bot.inline_button_press))
```

Second, define an id of some sort in the button's call back data. e.g.

```
# when creating the inline buttons
button_value_dict = {
    "ID": "XYZ"
}
button_value = json.dumps(button_value_dict)

key_row.append(
    InlineKeyboardButton(button_text, callback_data=button_value)
)
```

Third, in the handler, get the button data, and check in some form of persistent storage if the ID has already been used/addressed. If not, add it to the storage and perform action. The functions (get_meta and set_meta) are just examples. e.g.

```
# in the routine that handles inline buttons presses
# inline_button_press in the example above
# update is a passed parameter

query = update.callback_query
button_data = query.data
button_data_dict = json.loads(button_data)
button_id = button_data_dict.get("ID")

var_value = get_meta (var=button_id)
if var_value is None:

    # first time button press
    # record this ID as used
    set_meta (var=button_id, value="used")

    # do your stuff

else:
    # someone has already pressed the button
    # do whatever
```